# ExpressJS not showing debug messages

Tags: node.js, express

I am using ExpressJS and would like to display internal debug messages, like here https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html.

When I am using this command in VS Code (Windows Powershell) "`set DEBUG=express:*; node ./dist/app.js" it is starting my Node/Express Server, however it does not display any debug messages. Do I have to add something to my code so it works?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same in windows command prompt and it worked there just exchanged the semicolon for an ampersand.

```
set DEBUG=express:* & node ./dist/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

"Express uses the debug module internally to log information about route matches, middleware functions that are in use, application mode, and the flow of the request-response cycle."
Do you have this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug
And there is no semicolon between the statements.

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering. I made it work in windows cmd with "set DEBUG=express:* & node ./dist/app.js" ... I thought the powershell semicolon does the same as cmd ampersand. Apparently I am wrong.